# Attempt to present x whose view is not in the window hierarchy issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, view, hierarchy

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2V9ui.jpg)
https://github.com/Lime777/On-The-Map

The answers I've found on stack overflow contains code thats been discarded by apple. I created a login screen that uses an API to get an object back. If its login username/password isn't successful id like to simply have an alert pop up but the error im getting is:

"Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x1248e4a00> on <On_The_Map.LoginScreenViewController: 0x124605290> (from <On_The_Map.LoginScreenViewController: 0x124605290>) whose view is not in the window hierarchy.
"
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You are trying to presenting both alert at a time (loginChecker and loginRequestHandler). You can solve by if you get error from loginChecker then show only error from loginChecker function else call login function

Comment: Please paste your code as text, not as an image.